# Loop thru subdirectories and execute

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, subdirectory

I run the following in a cmd prompt in order to convert .webp files to .jpg, but have to go into each subfolder, one at a time, and open a new command prompt window, ad infinitum...

```
for %f in (*.webp) do "X:\12X\11Web\Games\webp (WEBPs)\libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x86\bin\dwebp.exe" -o "%~nf.jpg" "%f"
DEL "*.webp"
EXIT
```

I want to create a batch file that will cycle thru main folder as well as each subfolder tree, executing the above. I've gleaned from some other stackoverflow posts the following, but it's erroring out.

```
@echo off
FOR /d /r %%i IN (*) DO (
   pushd "%%i"
COMMAND HERE????????
   popd
)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have two ways to do this. Either `pushd` to the directory where the file is found, run the command, test if the `jpg` file exists then delete the `webp` file:

Note, this is meant for a `batch-file` and not `cmd`.

```
@echo off
for /R %%f in (*.webp) do (
    pushd "%%~dpf"    
    "X:\12X\11Web\Games\webp (WEBPs)\libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x86\bin\dwebp.exe" -o "%%~nf.jpg" "%%~nxf"
    if exist "%%~nf.jpg" del /Q "%%~nxf"
    popd
)
```

Or you can simply run it by converting without `pushd` by simply telling it the full path to file and output file:

```
@echo off
for /R %%f in (*.webp) do (
    "X:\12X\11Web\Games\webp (WEBPs)\libwebp-1.0.2-windows-x86\bin\dwebp.exe" -o "%%~dpnf.jpg" "%%~f"
    if exist "%%~dpnf.jpg" del /Q "%%~f"
)
```